# Angularjs reload controller when click on href

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am beginner in Angular!
Help me, please!
There is a webapp (local directories browser).
I have app.js:

```
var currentPath = "http://localhost:9298/api/browse";

angular.module("browserApp", [])
    .controller("BrowseController", function ($scope, $http) {
        function getDirectoryBrowseModel(path) {
            $http.get(path, { responseType: "JSON" })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.model = response.data
            });
        };
        getDirectoryBrowseModel(currentPath);
    });
```

and html in index.cshtml:

```
<div ng-controller="BrowseController">
 <span ng-repeat="drive in model.Drives">
{{drive.Name}}
</span>

<div>{{model.CurrentDrive.Name}}</div>

<div>{{model.CurrentDirectory.Path}}</div>

<div ng-repeat="dir in model.Directories">
    <a href="#" onclick='$state.reload();'>{{dir.Name}}</a>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="file in model.Files">
    {{file.Name}}
</div>
```

When I run app first time, then It works succesfully and I get my **model** in my app.js($scope.model = response.data) and in index.cshtml I have my list of directories and files and drives ...

What to do???
When I click on {{dir.Name}} I want to reload app.js controller( or getDirectoryBrowseModel(currentPath)), with new value of currentPath, for example: currentPath = "[http://localhost:9298/api/browse?path=C:\](http://localhost:9298/api/browse?path=C:%5C)";. And I want to see new all directories and files in view index.cshtml.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of user2954587 helped me to make the right decision.

The right decision is: added function **`$scope.clickToPath`** to **app.js** and then added
**`ng-click='clickToPath("http://localhost:9298/api/browse?path=" + dir.Path)'`**
to **a href** in **index.html.**

**app.js:**

```
var currentPath = "http://localhost:9298/api/browse";

angular.module("browserApp", [])
.controller("BrowseController", function ($scope, $http) {
    function getDirectoryBrowseModel(path) {
        $http.get(path, { responseType: "JSON" })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.model = response.data
        });
    };
    getDirectoryBrowseModel(currentPath);

    $scope.clickToPath = function (path) {
        getDirectoryBrowseModel(path);
    }
});
```

in **index.cshtml:**

```
<div ng-controller="BrowseController">
 <span ng-repeat="drive in model.Drives">
{{drive.Name}}
</span>

<div>{{model.CurrentDrive.Name}}</div>

<div>{{model.CurrentDirectory.Path}}</div>

<div ng-repeat="dir in model.Directories">
    <a href="" id="{{dir.Name}}" ng-click='clickToPath("http://localhost:9298/api/browse?path=" + dir.Path)'>{{dir.Name}}</a>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="file in model.Files">
    {{file.Name}}
</div>
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

you can use `$window` from your controller and that will reload the page with a new url

```
<div ng-repeat="dir in model.Directories">
    <a href="#" ng-click='updateUrl()'>{{dir.Name}}</a>
</div>


# in controller 
updateUrl = function() {
   $window.location.href = 'my/path'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question the answer might be to use angular-ui-router for changing the states https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

var currentPath = "http://localhost:9298/api/browse"; - It's path to API on some service and I send it to my controller in
function getDirectoryBrowseModel(path) {
            $http.get(path, { responseType: "JSON" })
            ...
I want to change my parameter path in getDirectoryBrowseModel(path) and refresh my data in view(index.cshtml) - result: new files and directories in view